# Instantiating Chaincode in Hyperledger Composer with local npm registry

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to instantiate a chaincode in an environment without any Internet connection. As the chaincode container will issue `npm install` upon instantiation, I added a new container called `npmregistry` in the `docker-composer.yml` so that it is provisioned alongside the rest of the Fabric containers and belongs to the same docker network (composer_default). Note I'm using the `fabric-tools` downloaded from https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html)

```
npmregistry:
    container_name: npmregistry
    image: verdaccio/verdaccio
    volumes:
      - /home/user/repo/:/verdaccio/storage/
    ports:
      - 4873:4873
```

in the npmConfig config, i put: registry=http://npmregistry:4873/ and I issued the commands to deploy the BNA

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile ~/Downloads/vehicle-manufacture-network.bna -o npmrcFile=/home/user/npmConfig

composer network start -n vehicle-manufacture-network -V 0.2.4-deploy.0 -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -A admin -S adminpw -f networkadmin.card
```

However, the chaincode container does not see, to resolve the verdaccio (npmregistry) container
[image]

I made sure that the verdaccio container is in the same network as others and issuing a `wget http://npmregistry:4873/` from the peer container is successful. Thus i "cheated" a bit and attempted to hardcode the docker network gateway IP address into npmConfig

```
registry=http://172.18.0.1:4873/
```

I restarted deploying all over again, now it works. Seeing the verdaccio logs below, as there's no internet access, it fallbacks to the local repo (packages already available in the folder)

But during deployment, I received the following error:

```
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: received trailing metadata size exceeds limit
```

Looking into the Peer logs, I found the following:

```
2018-04-18 00:47:41.913 UTC [util] DockerBuild -> DEBU 4b7 Attempting build with image hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-1.1.0
2018-04-18 00:48:26.098 UTC [chaincode-platform] func1 -> ERRO 4b8 Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.9: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0

> x509@0.3.3 install /chaincode/output/node_modules/x509
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN nodejs.org:443
gyp ERR! stack     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (dns.js:55:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.13.0-38-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /chaincode/output/node_modules/x509
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated. My environmnent:

- Composer 0.19.0
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Hyperledger Fabric v1.1.0

Comment: You will probably see more detail for the error if you look in the log for the Peer.

Comment: Yes, i attached the Peer logs

Comment: So a couple of things come to mind. The resource exhausted error implies that you might have run out of memory or disk space. Also for the npm registry did you also load all the dependency tree package into it, there would be roughly 300 npm packages needed